# Difficulties with android on click listener

Tags: android

firstly I have to write that I have just started my adventure with android, I'm building simple menu and as far as I have about and exit button working :), I've tried with start button but it doesn't listen at all, If You have any suggestions what to do with it I would more than happy :)

main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
 View startButton = findViewById(R.id.start_button);
 startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
 View whereButton = findViewById(R.id.where_button);
 whereButton.setOnClickListener(this);
 View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
 aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
 View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
 exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {

switch (v.getId()) {

case R.id.about_button:
Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
startActivity(i);
break;
case R.id.exit_button:
finish();
break;
case R.id.start_button:
i = new Intent(this, Start.class);
startActivity(i);
break;
}
}
```

Strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">City Inspector</string>
<string name="main_title">Ldz Inspector</string>
<string name="start_title">Profile</string>
<string name="start_label">START</string>
<string name="where_label">WHERE AM I?</string>
<string name="option_label">OPTIONS</string>
<string name="about_label">ABOUT</string>
<string name="create_label">CREATE PROFILE</string>
<string name="browse_label">BROWSE MAP</string>
<string name="exit_label">EXIT</string> 
<string name="about_text">\
about program things

</string>
</resources>
```

start.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.start);
}
}
```

start.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/background"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:padding="20dip"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center" >
<TextView
android:text="@string/start_title"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
android:textSize="24.5sp" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/Create_Profile"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/create_label" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/Browse_Map"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/browse_label" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

!!EDIT:

Sorry I knew I forgot to post something :), here is the AndroidManifest :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="menu.dot"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
<activity android:name="MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

</activity>
<activity android:name=".About">
android:label="@string/about_title" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Exit">
andorid:label="@string/exit_title">    
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Start">
andorid:label="@string/start_title">

</activity>
/application>
</manifest>
```

Please check the start.xml edition

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/background"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:padding="20dip"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center" >
<TextView
android:text="@string/main_title"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
android:textSize="24.5sp" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/start_button"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/start_label" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/where_button"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/where_label" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/option_button"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/option_label" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/about_button"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/about_label" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/exit_button"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/exit_label" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does DDMS tell you something? Give you any info about why it isn't starting your Activity?

Comment: As far as I can see everything looks just fine. What I cannot see: is start.class deriving from Activity? Is start.class declared inside your manifest? Also put a log inside the onClick() method with Log.d("mainActivity", "onClick triggered") and inside every case statement to see if it gets triggered

Comment: thx rafael T, I'll check it in a sec

Comment: jezzzz now if I click on the START it is constantly taking me to about section

Comment: An android application doesn't need an Exit button in 99,9% of all cases. I would you suggest to read this: http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/05/when-to-include-exit-button-in-android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, you don't need to implement an `onClickListener` and check which button was clicked. Android offers you the neat way to specify the method used to handle the onClick-event by simply using the [`onClick`-attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick) for the button in your XML-Layout file.

Consider the following layout:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/some_button"
  android:onClick="someButtonsAction"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_content"
/>
```

The Activity presenting this button will now need to have a method like this:

```
public void someButtonsAction(View v){
  // Do your onClick stuff here
}
```

The supplied `View v`-argument is the clicked view itself. The whole thing is also illustrated [in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) on the top if the page.

This gives you the opportunity to make your code more readable and you don't need to get all the buttons from the layout, add them an onClickListener and decide which button was clicked (in the listener).

Comment: @user552629 so, you should up-vote good answers and accept the best one.

Comment: will keep it for a second longer, I totally dk what to do now, the solution u provide works for me only yesterday. I didn't change anything just start it to see how cool it looks :), and nothing happend

Comment: There must be some kind of error. Otherwise try a clean build.

Comment: I'm a little bit angry with it, maybe the Netbeans is not a best IDE for android?

Comment: This should not be a problem with the IDE. You can use whatever IDE you like. Does it work now or not?

Comment: I don't see any answer from you. In the questions XML-file, there are no `onClick`-attributes.

Comment: sorry, I've put a comment before I put an answer :), it is now

Answer (score 0):

Do you register 'Start' activity in AndroidManifest.xml?
If you did not register activity in AndroidManifest.xml, you are not able to run the acticity.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your main.xml?  I tried out your code making assumptions about what your main.xml looks like and start activity worked just fine (i.e., start layout displayed).

Comment: I've put it in the main post second ago

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  I did have to first clean up the bottom of your string resource xml, since you have 2 exit_label strings, and your "about_text" string gave me null pointer exception: <string name="exit_label">EXIT</string>  
<string name="about_text">\ 
about program things 
</string> 
<string name="exit_label">EXIT</string>

Comment: hmm, that's way strange. I don't know if u check updated version [ done it like an hour or more ago ] but now the problem looks like this: when I press start it takes me to the about page, when I click about it takes me to the about page.

Comment: Did you try showing values in logcat that follow the code trail you think it is supposed to take?  i.e., Log when you are in on click and the view id value, log which case you are in, log when you are in other activity, etc.  Maybe there will be a clue there.  Maybe you just need to fix project.

Comment: And, sorry, just in case I wasn't clear, by by fix project I mean right click on project name, android tools, fix project properties.

Answer (score 0):

mainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
View startButton = findViewById(R.id.start_button);
startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
View whereButton = findViewById(R.id.where_button);
whereButton.setOnClickListener(this);
View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {


switch (v.getId()) {

case R.id.about_button:
Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
startActivity(i);
break;
case R.id.exit_button:
finish();
break;

}
}
public void StartCl(View v){
Intent idd = new Intent(this,Start.class);
startActivity(idd);
}
}
```

Main.xml

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/start_button"
android:onClick="StartCl"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/start_label" />
```

Comment: You are assigning the `onClick`-Listener in the Layout and in Code. Delete the in-code assignment and it should work. Also, you should add details to your question and not create a new answer except you want to answer your own post.

Comment: hmm u mean to kick out this section public void onClick(View v) {}? But when I delete it, I got some errors with startButton.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: You should kick out this `startButton.setOnClickListener(this);``.